# Excel - Filter multiple columns

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a list of contact persons for my mailing list and would like to be able to filter the list by the persons interests, which in this example is *food* and *culture*.
However, I would like to include multiple filtered columns in the results, for example an e-mail might be relevant for people interested in *food* or *culture*. Therefore, I would like to filter by "Yes" in both columns with the result that row 2 and 3 is still showing. Is this possible?

[image: Excel sheet]

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is to add a helper column to filter by. In this case, I would add a column called "Food OR Culture", with the following formula:

```
=IF(OR([@Food]="Yes",[@Culture]="Yes"),"Yes","No")
```

This will return "Yes" if either Food or Culture is "Yes", and will return "No" if both Food and Culture are "No". You can change this formula's logic to include more tests in the OR statement, or more logical comparisons to achieve whatever combination you would like if your data is larger than this example. Simply put all the logic in the conditional part of the IF statement.

Then, simply filter by the helper column by "Yes".

I hope this helps - Cheers and Good Luck!